# Thymeleaf: Is there something similar to th:classappend to remove a class value?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to show one alert in some screen with this code:

```
<div id="errorDiv" class="alert alert-danger hidden">
    <label id="errorLabel"></label>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
```

By default, errorDiv div is hidden because it has the value hidden in the class attribute (I'm using bootstrap).

I would like to find in [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) something similar something similar to [th:classappend](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending) but instead of adding a value, removing the 'hidden' value in the class attribute to show the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use conditional css class include with **elvis operator**, something like:

```
<div id="errorDiv" class="alert alert-danger"  th:classappend="*{isError}?:'hidden'">
    <label id="errorLabel"></label>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
```

this should append `'hidden'` to the class attribute only if `*{isError}` is `null`.

see http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator

Comment: Thanks. I've had to add the character **:** to your expression and it works `th:classappend="*{isError}?:'hidden'"`

Comment: @AndrésCuadrosSuárez I think it should be `th:classappend="not *{isError} ? 'hidden'"`, because with `?:` the value of `isError` will be appended to class if `*{isError}` evaluates as `true`.